# What does `return false && <div />` actually return? Why does it not break my React Code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

```
const Test = () => {
  return (
    false && <div> hello </div>
  )
}
```

This does not return `<div>hello</div>` since the first operand is (literally) `false`. But what is being returned here when using this in React? Why does this not break my code?

So far I always used to do this:

```
if (condition) { 
   return <div>hi</div>
 } else {
   return </>
}
```

But it seems it's fine to just do

```
   return condition && <div>hi</div>
```

Are there any gotchas here?

Comment: It returns `false`. Why *would* it break your React code? See e.g. https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boolean` is a valid React Node type; here is the all valid types from typescript:

```
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

```js
function App(){
 console.log("rendered correctly")
 return false
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yep. The document just renders in the DOM as `<div id="root"></div>`, as if `<App/>` was not there.